# Nuget package source is unchecked automatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have added our org specific [nuget](/questions/tagged/nuget) package sources that has urls pointing to our local network for which I have complete access. After adding it by checking the checkbox in the package manager settings and closing the window, when I check the list of package sources again, one specific package source is getting removed ("unchecked") automatically. Either [visualstudio](/questions/tagged/visualstudio) or [nuget](/questions/tagged/nuget) extension removes the source.  The same source was working sometime back. Not sure if it has anything to do with VS/OS updates. At the same time, other custom package sources are working and other team members are not facing this issue.

Comment: Could you share the detailed steps and the specific source url? I will try reproduce this issue in my side. And after adding new package source, check the NuGet.Config file which stored in C:\Users\UserName \AppData\Roaming\NuGet. Make sure the package source is listed in <packageSources> node and not listed in <disabledPackageSources>.

Comment: That url was there in the "disabled" list. Removed. And it is working. I am trying to reproduce by adding the url in the "disabled" list again, but still it is working and I couldn't reproduce. Not sure this file change triggered something. Anyhow It is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the NuGet.Config file, DisabledPackageSources tag shows you the sources which are currently disabled, so if you want to make them be active, add the sources under the ActivePackageSource. Anyway, since it works well now after you edit the DisabledPackageSources, at least, we make sure that it would be related to the Nuget.config file. I post it as the answer.

Comment: I have   <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource> and nothing in the disabled package sources. this still not keeping my custom source enabled.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Note that as well as `NuGet.Config` file in ``%AppData%\NuGet\`` there could also be one in your solution folder.

Answer (score 12):

Jack's answer did not fix my issue. I ended up having to delete my private nuget store, and recreate it with a different name. somehow that fixed it. I checked all locations a NuGet.Config file could be stored, and didn't find a single reference to disabledPackageSources.

I hope my workaround helps someone else avoid the hours of lost time.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well! Just delete the package source and add a new one with the same URL but a different name.

Comment: No matter what I did, I could not get my package source "nuget.org" to be enabled. I renamed it to "MS nuget" and everything was fine again. I am using a solution specific .nuget folder and have other private sources configured.

Comment: Just note renaming to different name and then back to original worked for me.

Comment: Ugh, similar issue here. Nuget was fine for a couple of weeks; now I have the same problem again. First trying a Visual Studio update, and then delete-re-add route.